# Can I use an AngularJS Module multiple times on the same page?

Tags: html, angularjs

is it possible to use an AngularJS module multiple times in the same html file?
For Example:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("theApp", []);
app.controller("theController", function($scope)
{
    $scope.string = "hello there!";
});
</script>
<div id = "div1" ng-app = "theApp" ng-controller = "theController">
    {{string}}<br>
    <input ng-model = "string"> 
</div>
<div id = "div2" ng-app = "theApp" ng-controller = "theController">
    {{string}}<br>
    <input ng-model = "string"> 
</div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible? Yes. You can do it with manual **bootstrap** (by `id`): remove the second `ng-app="theApp"`, and add `angular.element(document).ready(function() { angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("div2"), ['theApp']);});`. But why would you do that?

Comment: Using same module at multiple places in a html does not make any sense.

Comment: I think you would like to use same components twice on page, not angular module. Component is a smaller part of your spa app, which is recommended to use several times in cases as lists, iterable objects and others.

Comment: @Oleksiy, yes, I want to use the same variables, Arrays and functions in multiple div-boxes without create a Controller for each of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with manual bootstrap (by id): remove the second ng-app="theApp", and add `angular.element(document).ready(function() { angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("div2"), ['theApp']);});`

Thanks to Aleksey Solovey